# Error saving an attribute on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, attributes

I cannot add a new attribute. When I put all the information and hit the save button I get an error :

> "Class Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json does not exist"

How to solve this issue?

Comment: What version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

check if the Serialize folder exits under vendor/magento/framework. If not try adding the serialize folder.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that some custom module silently depends on the Magento version 2.2+ without a dependency declared it in the `composer.json`. Try to search in your project which module is using this class and try to downgrade it to an older version compatible with your Magento version.